# Asp.Net 5 class library DataAnnotation errors

Tags: asp.net, data-annotations

I just added a class library project to my new solution and am only given the option of the new class library type. I created my domain classes, which use EF data annotations from System.Component.DataAnnotations. The classes themselves have no errors but the project wont build. I get these errors.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   TraderToolkit2016.DomainClasses..NET Platform 5.4   C:\Users\Thomas Donino\Documents\GitHubVisualStudio\TraderToolkit2016\TraderToolkit2016.DomainClasses\AppClasses\DailyClose.cs

I have the assembly referenced. Why am I getting these errors?

Here is my project.json file, DataAnnotations added automatically from VS right click.

```
{
 "version": "1.0.0-*",
 "description": "TraderToolkit2016.DomainClasses Class Library",
 "authors": [ "Thino" ],
 "tags": [ "" ],
 "projectUrl": "",
 "licenseUrl": "",

 "frameworks": {
   "net451": {
     "frameworkAssemblies": {
       "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0.0"
     }
   },
   "dotnet5.4": {
     "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
       "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
       "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
       "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
       "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: show your project.json file

Comment: see the updated post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mean that you are making your project compatible with 2 platforms. one is net451 and another is dotnet5.4.

```
"frameworks": {
   "net451": {
     "frameworkAssemblies": {
       "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations": "4.0.0.0"
     }
   },
```

This means that you have added reference of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations only to net451 target. and that's why you get following error:

```
are you missing an assembly reference?) TraderToolkit2016.DomainClasses..NET Platform 5.4
```

Notice the 5.4 in the end of error message.

Now the solution is to either remove dotnet5.4 if you dont need it or add a reference of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to dotnet5.4 to it as well. You can do that by simply installing this nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/4.0.11-beta-23516

Or simply modifying the file so that it looks like this:

```
"dotnet5.4": {
     "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
       "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
       "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
       "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
       "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
       "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
     }
   }
```

Comment: the edit worked. Man they made this a difficult process and there is little documentation to explain the travails of getting this done properly

Comment: tell me about it. I have spent hours and days to understand this shit. it cant get more complicated than this.

Comment: if I want to only target .net451 can I just remove the whole reference in project.json for that? and delete the ,Net Platform 5.4 under references?

Comment: yeah, you can remove the "dotnet5.4" section completely then,